# How to write a multi-file NPM package with Brunch

Tags: npm, brunch

I have a multi-file project, with ES6 style `export`s and `import`s.

I'm using Brunch to concatenate these files into 1 `main.js` file that will serve as the `main` for an NPM package.

To specify the API of my package, I need to have `export`s in `main.js`. But when Brunch concatenates my `js` files, I am worried that (1) `export`s that are meant for internal `import`s and (2) `export`s meant for my API will both look the same.

Looking at the generated `main.js` file it seems like the `export`s I write in my source code get wrapped into modules, but none of these are top-level exports like the ones needed for NPM packages.

How can I let NPM distinguish between these two types of `export`s? Specifically, how can I have `export`s in the `main.js` file generated by Brunch concatenation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brunch is [not designed for writing libraries](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/issues/713), but rather for building apps.

I don't need to concatenate files at all to publish them to NPM, so instead I have used [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) with React and ES6 presets to transform my ES6 `.jsx` files to ES5 `.js` files.

I then make one file (eg. `main.js`) where I export my library and set that as the `main` in `package.json`.

I can then use Brunch to create an app with the React skeleton (`brunch new -s brunch/with-react`), `npm install <my-package>`, and `import` my library within my app.